# Archiving Log when size reached

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, logging, nlog

Trying to configure my NLOG to archive log file when 200MB size reached, but now with the configuration shown below it overwrites same file when size is reached.

```
 <target name="debug-file"
            xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${basedir}/Log//log-debug-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.txt"
            layout="${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}  ${date}  ${pad:padding=2:inner=${threadid}}  ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
       archiveAboveSize="209715200"
           archiveNumbering="Sequence"
       concurrentWrites="true"
           keepFileOpen="false"
       archiveFileName="log-debug-{####}.txt"

    />
```

My goal is to have a several (as needed) files with the size of 200MB (or less) per same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to archive the old log files to some other directory like archives.

Modify archiveFileName attribute to some thing like

```
archiveFileName="${basedir}/Log/archives/log-debug.{#####}.txt"
```

Here is the full target node

```
<target name="debug-file"
            xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${basedir}/Log/log-debug-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.txt"
            layout="${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}  ${date}  ${pad:padding=2:inner=${threadid}}  ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
       archiveAboveSize="209715200"
           archiveNumbering="Sequence"
       concurrentWrites="true"
           keepFileOpen="false"
       archiveFileName="${basedir}/Log/archives/log-debug.{#####}.txt"

    />
```

Please take a look at https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target#size-based-file-archival for more details.

Comment: This works for me, but still don't understand why another directory needed?

Comment: I have not had a chance to try it, but can you verify what happens if you keep filename same as before fileName="${basedir}/Log/log-debug-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.txt", but modify archiveFileName="${basedir}/Log/log-debug.{#####}.txt" to see if the archived files are created in the same folder?